How to fix "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cairo'" for manim
I am trying to install Manim via Anaconda and by following the steps in this guide: https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/installation/conda.html
I managed to create a conda environment, activate it and install Manim and all its dependencies via these command.
conda create -n my-manim-environment
conda activate my-manim-environment
conda install -c conda-forge manim

But whenever I run the command manim from the path of my conda evriroment I get this error.
  File "C:\Users\Hooman\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\manim\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .animation.composition import *
  File "C:\Users\Hooman\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\manim\animation\composition.py", line 15, in <module>
    from manim.scene.scene import Scene
  File "C:\Users\Hooman\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\manim\scene\scene.py", line 41, in <module>
    from ..camera.camera import Camera
  File "C:\Users\Hooman\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\manim\camera\camera.py", line 14, in <module>
    import _cairo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cairo'


I am on windows 11 and I am using Anaconda 24.5.0 and Python 3.12.3 (I cant check my manim version because manim commands wont work).
I have tried reinstalling Manim multiple times via Anaconda and remaking and reactivating my conda enviroment but nothing seems to work.

I fixed it. For anyone that has the same issue I fixed it by choosing the python version in this command -> conda create -n my-manim-environment as 3.11.9 so it would look something like this -> conda create -n my-manim-environment python=3.11.9 (I also had to reinstall Anaconda).

C:\Users\Hooman\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\manim\__init__.py doesn't look like you ran manim from an environment created from an anaconda base, but from a miniconda base env. By reinstalling, you probably fixed a different underlying issue
